# Zoeppritz equations

Tags: seismology, seismic

I have a question regarding zoeppritz equations. The equations from Telford are as follwoing:

[image]

When trying to put in a matrix form, by converting amplitudes to reflection and transmission coefficients, doing so, by dividing by 'A0'

Comparing my results and the standard matrix form of Zoeppritz equation, I found that the last column in the "A" matrix has an opposed sign. What am I missing ? How can i convert these set of equations to the matrix form.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you've made more mathematics mistakes than just that one that you noticed. Double / triple check your work, and then ask a coworker to go over what you've done.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. you might see difference, but it is just switching between equation 1&2 and 3&4 inside the matrix. but the only difference is the sign of the last column. It will be great if you point out the mistake. Thank you

Comment: The middle and last blocks of equations are not consistent with one another. It appears that the middle  block of equations is consistent with the first four equations, although you did not explain what those modified terms are. You did not just switch equations 1&2 and equations 3&4 inside the matrix. (And why did you do that?) You also negated the sign of the last column of matrix. Why did you do that?